# Terminology Question About Equalizers

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Just a quick terminology question:

Let 
$$A\rightarrow B \rightrightarrows  C$$
be an equalizer diagram in which the composition $A\rightarrow C$ is an isomorphism.

Is there a standard name for such diagrams?

Comment: $B\rightrightarrows C$ is the diagram.  The $A\to B$ arrow is part of the cone over the diagram.

Comment: @DerekElkins:  I take your point. But it also seems to me that it's quite common in published mathematics to see the assertion that a certain square of morphisms is a pullback diagram, so while I admit to abusing language, I think it's a pretty standard form of abuse.

Comment: You may want to look at absolute and [split equalizers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+equalizer), and absolute/split (co)limits in general.  Not quite the same thing but maybe relevant.

Comment: @WillO: Can you name a class of natural examples of such equalizers?

Comment: @HeinrichD: Every split short exact sequence of modules gives a split equalizer with one of the parallel arrows being zero.

Comment: @HeinrichD:  Briefly:  Let ${\cal C}$ be the category $X\rightrightarrows Y\rightarrow Z$ (where both compositions are equal).  Then there exists a Grothendieck topology for which the presheaf $F_Z\rightarrow F_Y \rightrightarrows F_X$ is a sheaf   iff the corresponding equalizer diagram $E\rightarrow F_Y\rightrightarrows F_X$ is of the type described.